# How to remove apps of the previous OS after updating to windows 10

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, media-creation-tool

I have used the media creation tool to update my win7 computer to win10. The registry has been emptied, but the folder "program files" remain unchanged -- I can see my apps there.

I want to delete those apps, but since the registry is emptied, I can no longer uninstall them on the control pannel. Should I just delete the whole "program files" folder?

Answer (score 0):

If by "the registry has been emptied," you mean that there are no references you can find to those applications in the Windows Registry by searching, there is absolutely no reason not to delete all applications **that are not intrinsic to Window** in `C:\Program Files\` and also in `C:\Program Files (x86)\`. **Don't** remove Windows folders such as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared`, `C:\Program Files\Common Files`, etc. You might use a third-party tool such as [Wise Registry Cleaner](https://www.wisecleaner.com/wise-registry-cleaner.html) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/wise-registry-cleaner/) to search for any remaining references. Review any found before deleting the reference and associated application.

Even if there *were* references to those applications, though, deleting them would likely cause no permanent issues. For example, if you had installed *Notepad++*, made it the default to open Text files, then deleted *Notepad++*, Windows would simply ask what application to use next time you tried to open a Text file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what to do.

First of all make sure you have a backup of all your files (documents pictures softwares videos).

Then, open settings (Windows key + i ) > Click update and Security > Click Recovery > Choose "Reset this PC".

Now here you choose "Keep my files".This will remove any installed applications.

P.S - Never delete your "program files" folder unless it is in a drive other than your OS Drive